# Do all fields with internal absolute values arise as ordered fields or like $\mathbb{C}$ from them?

Tags: extension, ordered-fields

$\def\abs#1{\lvert#1\rvert}
\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}
\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$
(Crossposted [from math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2183566/57159) after 5 days with no correct answer.)

Let ​ $\langle F,+,\cdot\rangle$ ​ be a field, let $E$ be a *non-zero, strict* subring of that field, let ​ $\leq$
be a total order on $E$ that makes ​ $\langle E,+,\cdot,\leq\rangle$ ​ into an ordered ring, and let
$\abs\cdot : F\to E$ ​ be such that for all elements $x$ of $E$,
$$0\leq x \; \implies \; \abs x = x;$$
and, for all elements $y$ and $z$ of $F$,
$$0\leq \abs z,
\quad
\abs{y\cdot z} = \abs y\cdot\abs z,
\quad\text{and}\quad
\abs{y + z} \le \abs y + \abs z.
$$

> Does it follow that there exists an element $i$ of $F$ such that $i^2 = -1$ and, for all elements $z$ of $F$, there exist elements $a$ and $b$ of $E$ such that $z = a + b\cdot i$ and $|z|^2 = a^2 + b^2$?

One can verify that my assumptions force $E$ to be a sub*field* of $F$, and force $\abs\cdot$ to satisfy:  for all non-zero elements $y$ of $F$, $\abs y \neq 0$ and $\abs{y^{-1}} = \abs y^{-1}$.

Accordingly, a necessary condition for $i$ to satisfy my question's ​ $\langle a, b\rangle$ ​ condition
is that ​ $\{1, i\}$ ​ be a basis for $F$ as a vector space over $E$.

I have shown that letting $F$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and letting $\abs\cdot$ be the usual absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$ cannot yield a counterexample.

Lemma: ​ For all such structures, all real elements of $F$ are in $E$.

Proof: ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ Fix any such structure and let $z$ be any real element of $F$. ​ ​ ​ $\pm z = |z|\in E$, so at least one of ​ $\{z,-z\}$ ​ is in $E$. ​ ​ ​ Since $E$ is a subring, that means ​ $z\in E$.

Result: ​ Such structures cannot be counterexamples.

Proof:
Let $z$ be any element of $F$ that's not in $E$.

By the contrapositive of the lemma,  $|z|\not\in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, ​ $\Im(z) \neq 0$, ​so in particular ​ $z\neq 0$.

\begin{gather}
|z|^2 = \overline z\cdot z \\
\overline{z} = |z|\cdot|z|\cdot z^{-1} \in F \\
2\cdot\Im(z) \cdot i = \overline{z}-z \in F \\
\Im(z) \cdot i = \frac1 2\cdot2\cdot\Im (z)\cdot i \in F \\
i = \Im(z)\cdot i\Im(z)^{-1} = \Im(z)\cdot i\cdot\abs{\Im(z)\cdot i}^{-1} \in F \\
\Im(z) = \Im(z)\cdot i\cdot i^{-1} \in F \\
\operatorname{Re}(z) = z- \Im(z)\cdot i \in F.
\end{gather}
By the lemma, $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ and $\Im(z)$ are both in $E$.

Comment: There is only one algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 (up to isomorphism) of each cardinality. So your argument about $\mathbb{C}$ might go through for general algebraically closed fields of characteristic 0 (although I did not read it carefully enough to say).

Comment: I think the question makes no mention of "algebraically closed".  So couldn't you have a situation where the extension contains $\sqrt{-3}$ but doesn't contain $\sqrt{-1}$ ...

Comment: @IzaakMeckler, your comment is only true for *uncountable* cardinalities. The algebraic closures of $\mathbf Q$ and $\mathbf Q(x)$ are both countable but are not isomorphic.

Comment: Can we rule out the possibility that $F$ contains elements that are transcendental over $E$?